# Convergence of 3 dimension integral with a singularity refer to $\int_{B_{r_0}(0)}d^3x'\frac{\cos^2(\frac{|x'|\pi}{2r_0})}{|x-x'|}e^{i\omega |x-x'|}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to check if the following integral converges:

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$

> $$\int_{0}^{L_x}\int_{0}^{L_y}\int_{0}^{L_z}d^3x^{'}\frac{\sin^2(\frac{x_1^{'}\pi}{L_x})\sin^2(\frac{x^{'}_2\pi}{L_y})\sin^2(\frac{x_3^{'}\pi}{L_z})}{|x-x'|}e^{i\omega |x-x'|}$$

where $x'=(x_1^{'},x_2^{'},x_3^{'})$, and $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

The question arose when I wanted to compute the integral with Mathematica. When doing this numerically with Mathematica I get results which I have not expected.

If the integral above is to complicated one could alternatively also first look at the following integral:

> $$\int_{B_{r_0}(0)}d^3x'\frac{\cos^2(\frac{|x'|\pi}{2r_0})}{|x-x'|}e^{i\omega |x-x'|}$$
>   where $B_{r_0}(0)$ is the Ball with radius $r_0$ around 0.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous: is $x'$ a vector? if so, the sine functions are acting on its components, right? So the symbol $x'$ appears twice, meaning different things. Assuming I did understand the meaning of the integral, it seems it does converge for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: $d^3x'$ means $dx'dy'dz'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The integral always converges.

If the "singularity" at $x$ has positive distance from the domain you are integrating over, the answer is clear.

If the "singularity" is inside or on the boundary the domain, then switching to spherical coordinates centered at $x$ makes it clear also, as $\frac{1}{|x-x'|}$ becomes $\frac1r$ and you have an $r^2$ factor appearing in the (absolute value of the) determinant of the (Jacobi matrix of the) change of coordinates. The rest are bounded functions, so those have no impact on the integral whatsoever.

Comment: In spherical coordinates you have $\int_{...}^{...}d\phi'\int_{...}^{...}d\theta'\int_{...}^{...}dr' r'^2\sin(\theta')\frac{\sin^2(\frac{x'\pi}{L_x})\sin^2(\frac{y'\pi}{L_y})\sin^2(\frac{z'\pi}{L_z})}{|x-x'|}e^{i\omega |x-x'|}$ I don't see why it should converge now. The denominator converges for $x=x'$, but the term from the determinant is nonzero there.

Comment: Center the coordinates at $x$, not at zero.

Comment: Ok, I guess you mean a coordinate transformation $u=\omega(x-x')$ first? When I do this I obtain: $\int_{\omega x_1}^{\omega x_1-L_x}du_1\int_{\omega  x_2}^{\omega x_2-L_y}du_2\int_{\omega x_3}^{\omega x_3-L_z}du_3 \frac{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{L_x}(x_1-\frac{u_1}{\omega}))...}{u}e^{i u}$. Now I can switch to spherical coordinates $\int_{...}^{...}d\theta\int_{...}^{...}d\phi\int_{...}^{...}du u^2\sin(\theta) \frac{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{L_x}(x_1-\frac{u\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)}{\omega}))...}{u}e^{i u}$. Is this what you mean?